# rtl.css и media queries

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries, rtl

Есть элемент с классом `.block`.

Для него прописаны правила в трёх местах.

В style.css:

```
.block { float: left; }
```

В rtl.css:

```
.block { float: right; }
```

В media.css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .block { float: none; }
}
```

Почему для `rtl`-версии сайта медиа-запрос не выполняется?

В исходном коде видно, что файл `rtl.css` подгружается последним. Но разве медиа-запросы не имеют приоритет? Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Comment: Добавьте в ваш вопрос пример вашего `media`, может в нём проблема. И скажите, в каком файле лежит ваше `media`- правило.

Comment: посмотрите в консоли, какие стили и что влияет

Comment: В инспекторе видно, что правила из `rtl.css` перекрывают правила из `media.css`. Но почему? `rtl`-правила приоритетнее?

Comment: Имеет значение очередность подключения файлов стилей. Правила rtl перекрывают, потому что подключены позже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Медиа-запросы не имеют приоритета. Вот вам пример. Раскройте сниппет во весь экран и подвигайте окно браузера.

Нижний .block2 меняет цвет, а верхний .block - нет. Потому что медиа-запрос для верхнего блока перекрыт следующим правилом, которое гласит: фон всегда зеленый.

Так что если хотите, чтобы медиа-запросы работали, размещайте их ниже по тексту вашего файла css.

```css
.block,
.block2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .block {
    background: red;
  }
}

.block {
  background: green;
}

.block2 {
  background: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .block2 {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
```